# how to divide the sum of images by the total number of images in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to reproduce the code outline from [this segment of a research paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT1GK.jpg) using OpenCV (python):

My outcome for the mask doesn't look anything like what is in the paper.  You can see my outcome here or just run the python below: [binary_reference_coin_mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiPo8.jpg), [mean gradient map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrA2U.jpg), [mean_threshold_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSW7x.jpg)  -- without inverse on threshold it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9czRI.jpg).

I may not be dividing appropriately ([divide()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) doesn't seem to be appropriate for this as I am not dividing by an array) or interpreting the way to code the algorithm appropriately.   I think it is telling me to sum the Laplacian arrays divided by the total number of arrays then add that to the sum of Threshold arrays divided by the total number of arrays.

**Is the below python a correct interpretation of (sum of Laplacian) divided by n + (sum of Otsu Threshhold) divided by n ?**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import copy

urls = [
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/69.jpg", 
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/68.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/67.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/66.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/65.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/64.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/63.jpg",
    "https://coinmodel.s3.amazonaws.com/62.jpg",
]

i = 0
ddepth = cv2.CV_16S
#ddepth = cv2.CV_8U
kernel_size = 3

for url in urls:
    img = io.imread(url)    
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
    img_bgrL = cv2.cvtColor(img_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_bgrT = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgL = cv2.Laplacian(img_bgrL, ddepth, ksize=kernel_size)    
    ret, imgT = cv2.threshold(img_bgrT, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    if i != 0:
        Laplacian_sum = cv2.add(imgL, imgL_last)
        Threshold_sum = cv2.add(imgT, imgT_last)
    imgL_last = copy.copy(imgL) 
    imgT_last = copy.copy(imgT)
    i=i+1    
    
mean_gradient_map = Laplacian_sum / i
mean_threshold_image = Threshold_sum / i
binary_reference_coin_mask = cv2.add(mean_gradient_map, mean_threshold_image)

cv2.imshow("Laplacian mean", mean_gradient_map)
cv2.imshow("Threshold mean", mean_threshold_image)
cv2.imshow("binary_reference_coin_mask", binary_reference_coin_mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

why divide i ? -> /i add pixel RGB [255]+[255] = [255]

```
mean_gradient_map = Laplacian_sum
mean_threshold_image = Threshold_sum
```

```
#ret, imgT = cv2.threshold(img_bgr, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret, imgT = cv2.threshold(img_bgr, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

or

```
height, width = img_bgr.shape
if i != 0:
        Laplacian_sum = cv2.add(imgL, imgL_last)
        Threshold_sum = cv2.add(imgT, imgT_last)
        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                Laplacian_sum[y,x] = Laplacian_sum[y,x]/2
```

This is pixel RGB /2

or

numpy pixel img RGB result add / n

Comment: You can remove those `for` loops and just do `Laplacian_sum /= 2`.  OpenCV images in Python are simply NumPy arrays so take advantage of vectorisation.

Comment: I first received a "Bad argument" error from the final add() because of different types  int16 vs uint8, so I first tried convertScaleAbs() with poor results.  I then changed "Laplacian(img_bgrL, 0)" with interesting results but there is still a great deal of noise-- here is that update https://imgur.com/iJSxiew  Output here:

https://imgur.com/G9qLKgo binary_reference_coin_mask
https://imgur.com/gsIvLYA mean_gradient_map
https://imgur.com/WGGTP1A mean_threshold_image

also @rayryeng I could not get vectorization advantage to work, i suspect https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10565

Comment: Convert it to floating point first. I thought your inputs were floating point.